# scheme transform type(string to list)

Tags: types, scheme

first, I want to transform the string type data to list type in order to implement the "reverse" function.But, I can't do it!The code like:

```
(define p (open-input-file "test.txt"))
(define c (read-line p))
(close-input-port p)
(string->list c)
(reverse c)
```

I do not know where the errors are? Why cant i just transform the type. I need ur guys help, thankS!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(reverse (string->list c))
```

Remember: in Scheme all standard list functions return values that must be used or stored somewhere, they don't modify objects in-place.